# Optimizepress Header file modification

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have tried to edit the default header of Optimizepress, I have edited the blog header, but it seems I can't edit the default page header. On `header.php` its written

```
<?php op_theme_file('header') ?>
```

But I don't find the exact location where the header is located to modify.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Landing page :** optimizePressTheme/pages/landing/1/template.php

**Marketing :** optimizePressTheme/pages/marketing/1/template.php

**Membership:** optimizePressTheme/pages/membership/1/template.php

```
 op_theme_file('header')
```

header page is comes from the depend on your page it's come from base on landing, marketing, and  membership page ...

thanks.